# Use JSTL sql tag to show aggregate function result

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

```
<%int counter = 10; %>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Count</th>
 </tr>
     <c:forEach var="j" begin="1" end="8">

          <sql:query var="rs" dataSource="${xxxxx}"> 
             SELECT  count (*) from tickets where ticket_no = <%=counter%>
          </sql:query>

         <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
            <tr>
              <td><c:out value="${row.value}" /></td>
            <tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <% counter+=10; %>
     </c:forEach>
</table>
```

above is code which use JSTL SQL tag to get a resultset from the database. and run it for 8 times so the counter will go from 10 to 80 and give its value to the SQL ticket_no. but this code doesn't work... :( any ideas how to modify it? thanks.

Comment: "but this code doesn't work..." What do you mean by that?

Comment: oh~ probably I did not make me question clear. my question is since select count(*) only return one value, so we still need to use foreach to get that value. but I want to run this SQL for 8 times, and each time gives that SQL command different ticket_no so it will show different result, but above code doesn't show the answer correctly, any ideas how to modify it?

Comment: why are you  mixing the `jstl` with scriptlets . use `c:set`

Comment: the reason why I mix jstl with scriptlets is because I want the foreach to print out table rows for every resultset rows. btw can you explain more about how c:set work with this problem?